# disabling SAML on integration instance of Maximo 7.6

Tags: integration, saml, maximo

I have a system with Maximo 7.6 ( Webpshere 8.5) and SAML implemented at Gloabl Security Level.
There are two instances , on for UI and one for Integration ,would like to know the possibility of disabling SAML on integration instance alone by using Security Domain so that Integration framework authentication happens via Default File based realm.

Please share any documents available for same.

Comment: After number of trials ,I was able to configure Security Domains and now our Integration URL is not asking for SSO authentication where as UI URL goes through SSO authentication process

Comment: Might you answer your own question and provide the steps you took to arrive at your solution?

Comment: For configuring SAML ,I  had set up properties in Global Security -> Trust Association -> interceptors  and  specified targetURL, acsURL, login Error page and entity ID. For bypassing SSO on one instance , configure Security Domain , select that specific instance alone. In Trust Association ,select Customize for this domain and uncheck "enable trust Association".Configure all other properties as per Global settings. Create new user in Users and Group which will be tagged to default realm and in deployed application Security role to user group mapping ,map all authenticated in application realm

Comment: Please make your comment an answer and mark it as answer. You can answer your own question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For configuring SAML ,I had set up properties in Global Security -> Trust Association -> interceptors and specified targetURL, acsURL, login Error page and entity ID. For bypassing SSO on one instance , configure Security Domain , select that specific instance alone. In Trust Association ,select Customize for this domain and uncheck "enable trust Association".Configure all other properties as per Global settings. Create new user in Users and Group which will be tagged to default realm and in deployed application Security role to user group mapping ,map all authenticated in application realm